# How to generate UML Class Diagram from kotlin project

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, uml, class-diagram

I'm looking for a way to generate class diagrams starting from a project written in Kotlin that I have already created in android studio, can you recommend me some plugins that do it automatically or some tutorials on how to do it?

I tried to google but I only find answers to old questions and all for projects written in java.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is off-topic for SO. Please read the help as to which question can be asked and what makes up a good question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to either do it by hand, or use plugins that do a really bad job at creating a readable UML diagram.
If you need to do it automatically and happen to have IntelliJ Ultimate, export all of your Kotlin classes into a new project within IntelliJ and use their automatic UML diagram generator.